# Scroll a RecyclerView when scrolling second one

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have in my main activity 2 `RecyclerView`s: one is horizontal and the other is vertical. My problem is when I scroll down in the second recycler I want the upper recycler to be scrolled also, but its not. It is staying fixed.

This is my code:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
recylerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recylerViewLayoutManager);
recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, subjects,images);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);


MainGridRecView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.maingridrc);
MainGridRecViewLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context,2);
MainGridRecView.setLayoutManager(MainGridRecViewLayoutManager);
MainGridRecViewAdapter = new MainGridRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, subjects,images);
MainGridRecView.setAdapter(MainGridRecViewAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [`RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html) and scroll another [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) manually:

```
recyclerView1.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
        recyclerView2.setScrollX(dx);
        recyclerView2.setScrollY(dy);
    }
});
```

Although I do not get what effect you are trying to achieve, but at least you will get the concept.

Comment: i had a problem in the connection i couldnt post my full question anyway ill try this if it didnt qork ill explain more